# Malloc(1) is allocating 5 bytes

Tags: c, security, memory, malloc

```
 char* foo = malloc(sizeof(char));
*(foo + 1) = 'c';
```

In the debugger, I see that `foo` is a pointer to a char array of size `5`. Why is this?!

Comment: It's probably allocating some extra space to record the size of the allocation.

Comment: How do you see that it's an array of size 5?

Comment: What exactly is your debugger showing?  You are more likely misinterpreting the evidence than it actually allocated 5 bytes.  Note also that allocations are normally 8 byte aligned, and the actual amount of memory used includes a meta-data block used for heap management - that block precedes the pointer returned.  By overrunning the allocation as you have you are likely to corrupt the heap by modifying the meta-data of an adjacent block.  In this case because of 8-byte alignment you "_get away with it_".

Answer (score 4):

> In the debugger, I see that `foo` is a pointer to a char array of size 5. Why is this?!

Because your debugger is not perfect. When showing a `char *`, a debugger typically assumes that it points to a C string (an array of `char` terminated by the null character), and shows it that way. However, you only allocated 1 byte of data. The subsequent characters are previous contents of memory, which the debugger shows. In your case the memory happens to contain three more non-null characters before seeing a null, which is why the debugger is showing five chars in total.

Also, your code has a bug in that it writes outside the allocated bounds. `*foo = 'c'` is legal, as is `foo[0] = 'c'`, but `*(foo + 1) = 'c'` is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: It is not really a matter of the debugger being "imperfect" - that would be a scary thought - you need to trust your debugger.  It is more a matter that C has no intrinsic string data type, and the debugger is simply saying in the absence of semantic information "_if this `char*` is intended to be a string, this is the string_". It is down to the developer to interpret the presentation accordingly.  If it is intended to be a string you can see it is either not initialised or not correctly terminated.

Comment: @Clifford *It is not really a matter of the debugger being "imperfect"* - It's imperfect in the sense that it doesn't or can't ask malloc for the size of the allocated block, not in the sense of it being buggy or untrustworthy. Hopefully the rest of the answer makes that clear, even if the first sentence is, well, imperfect.

Comment: My point is that it is the language that is issue and the fact that memory allocation is provided by the library not the language.  My concern was only that if you cause people to doubt the _correctness_ of their debugger, they might avoid using it.  Here the point is rather to understand and interpret the information presented to the debugger correctly.  I understood what you were saying, but a novice might interpret it as "debuggers are useless".

Comment: @Clifford I fully understand your point, but reject the interpretation that the answer would cause the reader to doubt the correctness or usefulness of the debugger. Neither follows from the actual answer, and requires a specious misreading of the first sentence. The distinction between the language and the standard library notwithstanding, a sufficiently smart debugger could certainly do more with a pointer returned by `malloc()` - and some debuggers indeed do do more than others. There is nothing incorrect or even contentious about such a claim.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer exactly without knowing which compiler, runtime library, and os you use.

In general `malloc()` operations carve out space from a big area of RAM. It puts bookkeeping information before and after the space it gives you back, so when you `free()` the space it can make it available for another `malloc()`. If you overwrite that bookkeeping information chaos can ensue.

[`malloc()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html) does not promise to zero out the memory space it gives you. The contents of new memory space it gives you are, formally speaking, *unpredictable.* So, when you examine a newly allocated chunk of space with a debugger, you will see whatever data the previous user of that space left there. If you want your space to be zeroed use `calloc()`. (Hint: you probably do want it to be zeroed unless you're writing extraordinarily performance-critical code.)

Also, `malloc()` gives back word-aligned space.  If you do a series of several `malloc(3)` operations on a 64-bit machine each of them comes back with an address that's zero modulo 8. It typically allocates a bit of extra space to do that. But that is an implementation detail. Do not rely on it, or you'll be sorry.

**BEWARE**: You've heard of malware like WannaCry? And many others? That malware is made possible by code like in your example, which writes outside the bounds of the memory you requested from `malloc()`. When using `malloc()`, you **must** make sure you don't write out of those bounds. You're not being paranoid when you do that: cybercreeps both state-sponsored and otherwise are in fact plotting against you.  Seriously.

Better yet, use a language with native text-string and array data types.